# Argo-rollout implementation to have previous version when new version have errors

Tags: argo

I have problem because I need to implement argo-rollout because when we are deploying new version of application and it have some errors we want to have possibility to back to previous version. But we can't have two instances of our application because it is too big.
Its that even possible to implement?

Trying to read doc, googling and can't find answer